# Linux: how do I tar to a specific location?

Tags: linux, tar

I am currently backing up my system.  If I use

```
> tar cvpzf backup.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found--exclude=/backup.tgz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /
```

It says the system doesn't have enought space.

Right now, I have mount a usb in directory

```
~/mnt/sdc1
```

How do I tar the `backup.tgz` to this specific location?

Comment: Have you tried -C dir_name options with Tar command

Comment: No - `-C` is path to `source` files...

Comment: try this tar cvpzf  ~/mnt/sdc1/backup.tgz ........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to do two things. First insure that your drive is mounted, Then just provide the complete path to your backup location. E.g.

```
mount | grep -q ~/mnt/sdc1       # or just grep -q sdc1 (if it is the only sdc1)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    tar cvpzf ~/mnt/sdc1/backup.tgz ...
fi
```

note: the replace the ellipses with the rest of your `tar` command.